# How to distinguish "no value" from "empty value" when setting `l3keys`?

Tags: expl3, key-value, l3keys

I'm trying to create an option with `l3keys` such that, if it receives a value, even if an empty one, it gets added to a property list, but if it receives no value, it gets removed from the property list.

However, I don't seem to be able do distinguish `key` from `key=` in a `.code:n` "action".  I know that `.default:n` captures that situation, but it cannot receive a code block, just a value.  I also know that I can distinguish the situation in `\keyval_parse:nnn`, but I'd like this behavior in some options among the whole set, and using `\keyval_parse:nnn` for the whole thing would become complicated.

The MWE illustrates the situation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l__myprops_prop
\keys_define:nn { options }
  {
    mykey .code:n =
      {
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
          { \prop_remove:Nn \l__myprops_prop { mykey } }
          { \prop_put:Nnn \l__myprops_prop { mykey } {#1} }
        \prop_show:N \l__myprops_prop
      } ,
    mykey2 .code:n =
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
          { \prop_remove:Nn \l__myprops_prop { mykey2 } }
          { \prop_put:Nnn \l__myprops_prop { mykey2 } {#1} }
        \prop_show:N \l__myprops_prop
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey= }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey=val }
\prop_clear:N \l__myprops_prop
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2 }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2= }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2=val }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The log for this document contains:

```
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey}  =>  {}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.27 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey }
                                       
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey}  =>  {}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.28 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey= }
                                        
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey}  =>  {val}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.29 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey=val }
                                           
The property list \l__myprops_prop is empty
> .
<recently read> }
                 
l.31 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2 }
                                        
The property list \l__myprops_prop is empty
> .
<recently read> }
                 
l.32 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2= }
                                         
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey2}  =>  {val}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.33 \keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2=val }
```

Which shows that neither `key` nor `key=` pass the "no value" test, and both `key` and `key=` pass the emptiness test. Unfortunately, I cannot use emptiness to "signal" the removal, since "empty" is a valid value for the key in question. Is indeed `\keyval_parse:nnn` the only choice here?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible with `\keys_set:nn` (using documented interfaces).  There is a private boolean variable that holds the value/no-value state, but it's not used when the `.code:n` handler is used.  It would be nice to distinguish these cases, but I don't think a change is feasible at this point...

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik, I feared as much... :-( I'll have to rethink this here then. From the OPs perspective, your comment is a full answer. If you'd like to make it one, I'd be glad to accept it. Either way, thank you!

Comment: Conceptually, `l3keys` works on the idea that keys are properties, and thus there is no such thing as 'not having a value' for any key - once you create a key, it always has _some_ value even if that value is 'empty'.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the comment. What I'm trying to do is to get different behaviors for `key` and `key=` in a `.code:n` handler. So I might have expressed myself poorly, but since `\keyval_parse:nnn` recognizes this difference, I was hoping to grab that piece of information in `\keys_set:nn` too. And indeed, Skillmon provided a way which seems to be the proper one to do it.

Comment: @JosephWright Let me see if I get what you meant correctly. Are you saying that, even though I can technically recognize the difference between `key` and `key=`, I should not use that distinction at the user level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This builds on the same basic idea as @Phelype's answer, namely use `\c_novalue_tl` as a marker, but instead of wrapping `\keyval_parse:nnn` around `\keys_set:nn` this uses the `.default:x` handler to set the default value to `\c_novalue_tl`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l__myprops_prop
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myprops_handle:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
      { \prop_remove:NV \l__myprops_prop \l_keys_key_str }
      { \prop_put:NVn   \l__myprops_prop \l_keys_key_str {#1} }
    \prop_show:N \l__myprops_prop
  }
\keys_define:nn { options }
  {
     mykey  .code:n = \__myprops_handle:n {#1}
    ,mykey  .default:x = \c_novalue_tl
    ,mykey2 .code:n = \__myprops_handle:n {#1}
    ,mykey2 .default:x = \c_novalue_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey= }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey=val }
\prop_clear:N \l__myprops_prop
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2 }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2= }
\keys_set:nn { options } { mykey2=val }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, wow! We *can* have both `.code:` and `.default:` and `.code:` is executed after `.default:`. That's clever! Thank you! How did you find that out?

Comment: @gusbrs knowing much of the implementation helps :P But more seriously, take a look at the documentation in `texdoc interface3`, the description of the `.default:n` property is: "Creates a <default> value for <key>, which is used if no value is given. This will be used if only the key name is given, but not if a blank <value> is given: [code example]" The code example covers exactly your use case (well, not the property setting, but using the `.code:n` property). The `.default:n` property does nothing by itself, it just sets a default value used with whichever other property is defined.

Comment: :-) Well, I had. Currently `texdoc interface3` is deserving a dedicated keybinding here. And I was acquainted with the documentation of `.default:` in particular. I just didn't figure it out it could be used alongside `.code:`, much less of their execution order. The docs do say that some of the "actions"/handlers are mutually exclusive, but just gives some clear examples, not an exhaustive list. And I'd be willing to bet there's no word about `.code:` coming after `.default:`. I guess it takes "right eyes" to see it.  :-) Thanks once again!

Comment: "The code example covers exactly your use case". In hindsight, indeed it does. Damn, it is hard to have a thick skull!  ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs quick list of exclusive handlers: Every one except `.default:n`, `.initial:n`, `.groups:n`. Additionally `.value_required:n` and `.value_forbidden:n` are only mutually exclusive to each other and not to any other handler. (I hope I didn't forget something here...)

Comment: Good to know it, thanks again!

Comment: @gusbrs just in case you're not yet fully aware: `.default:n` is executed before anything else if you omitted a value, and only afterwards the other properties (which do some "action") are executed. Exception: if the `.value_required:n` property is `true` then `.default:n` isn't considered and an error thrown if you omitted the value (ergo, it is mutually exclusive with `.default:n` in some way, it doesn't remove that property, but renders it useless as long as `.value_required:n` remains `true`).

Comment: No, I was not, and I'm glad you told me. Put that way, it makes perfect sense that it is so, but it is not easy to infer it from the available information. Yet again, thank you! Btw, this is a valuable piece of information, so much so, I'd suggest you include it in the answer (if you'd like, that is). It is the right conceptual answer to the problem of "getting different behaviors from `key` and `key=` in a `.code:n` handler, it is hence quite useful, and undocumented (as far as I can see).

Comment: @gusbrs better idea: You could open an issue (or PR) at the LaTeX3 Github repository and suggest better wording for the `.default:n` documentation (I found it not that unclear, tbh.).

Comment: You are right, now that you explained it, I can get it better and agree it is not unclear. But it still was difficult for me to understand it. Anyway, I did open an issue suggesting a little more detail: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/989

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to distinguish `mykey` from `mykey={}` when it's declared with the `.code:n` handler.  Internally these cases are different, and there is a boolean variable that keeps track of that, but all using private variables from `l3keys`.

What you can do using the available interfaces is use `\keyval_parse:nnn`, as you suggested, to differentiate both cases, and then when `mykey` is used, turn that into `mykey = \c_novalue_tl`, then the code in your key can detect that using `\tl_if_novalue:nTF`.  This makes the parsing a bit slower than just using `\keys_set:nn` because some common bookkeeping code in `\keys_set:nn` is executed more often, but that's likely minimal.

The example below implements `\gusbrs_keys_set:nn`, which passes `\c_novalue_tl` to a key if no value is given:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \gusbrs_keys_set:nn #1 #2
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      { \__gusbrs_keys_set:nn {#1} }
      { \__gusbrs_keys_set:nnn {#1} }
        {#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gusbrs_keys_set:nn #1 #2
  { \use:x { \keys_set:nn {#1} { #2 = \c_novalue_tl } } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__gusbrs_keys_set:nnn #1 #2 #3
  { \keys_set:nn {#1} { #2 = #3 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l__myprops_prop
\keys_define:nn { options }
  {
    mykey .code:n =
      {
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
          { \prop_remove:Nn \l__myprops_prop { mykey } }
          { \prop_put:Nnn \l__myprops_prop { mykey } {#1} }
        \prop_show:N \l__myprops_prop
      } ,
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey }
\gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey= }
\gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey=val }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

This is printed on the terminal:

```latex
The property list \l__myprops_prop is empty
> .
<recently read> }
                 
l.35 \gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey }
                                              
? 
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey}  =>  {}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.36 \gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey= }
                                               
? 
The property list \l__myprops_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {mykey}  =>  {val}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.37 \gusbrs_keys_set:nn { options } { mykey=val }
                                                  
?
```

Comment: Ah, interesting approach! Thank you very much!

Comment: But, one question, what happens if I have other keys besides `mykey` and some of them receive no value (they either have a `.default:n` or are `.meta:n` action with value forbidden), what will happen to them?

Comment: @gusbrs Hm... Is “won't work” an acceptable answer? ;-) Sorry, I didn't think of that.  Maybe something with `\keys_set_groups:nnn`, and placing `mykey` (and other similar keys) in a separate group might work (guessing).  It's getting late, so I'll give it a try tomorrow, if you haven't managed by then

Comment: It is. ;-) The technical question is interesting, of course, but in practical terms, I think I'm likely approaching the problem from the wrong side. I have probably to reconsider how I'm organizing the UI. Possibly I'm overdoing the "user flexibility" side of things. Just so that I don't leave you in the dark, I have "translations" and an overriding value for "any language" which goes in this property. Once set globally, there is currently no way to unset it, only to set it to another value. But, does it need to be? Anyway, a problem for me to solve. Thanks again!

Comment: Phelype, I've accepted Skillmon's answer, because it works without tampering with the other keys. Yet, thanks again for the great stab at the problem. Btw, wrt Skillmon's solution, do you happen to know if the fact that both `.default:` and `.code:` are executed for a key in that order is an intended (just undocumented) feature or just plain luck?

Comment: Phelype, Skillmon also has an answer to the documentation question. It is there, "hidden in plain sight": the code example for the `.default:` handler...

Comment: @gusbrs Bah, I feel stupid for not thinking of that.  Indeed, Skillmon's method is _the_ right way to do this, no weird tricks needed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yay :) But I think making the boolean public that stores whether a value was present or not would do no harm, not cost anything (well, 5 lines of documentation), but give additional options to users.

Comment: @Skillmon Well, it is possible to check that a value was given by relying on the `.default:n`, but it feels workaroundish, when there's a boolean available. I think it wouldn't hurt... Could you please open an issue?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, please don't. I haven't thought of it either, and you went further than I did. What's left for me to "feel like"? rsrsrs (Btw, even in English, I was able to hear the "tche" after that "bah" ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik opened a PR.

Comment: @gusbrs No tchê, please ;-) I'm not gaúcho, but I lived there for 5 years and the "bah" just becomes part of your vocabulary after a while :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  :-)