# Presetting keys in l3keys

Tags: expl3, latex3, xkeyval, l3keys

As far as I am aware, there is no mechanism in `l3keys` to preset keys like the `xkeyval` supports.

I explicitly do *not* mean the `.default:n` specification in `l3keys`, since this is invoced if the `key` is given but no `=value` is present.

With the following definition

```
\keys_define:nn { module }
{
  keya      .tl_set:N  = \l_keya_tl,
  keya      .default:n = { foo },
  keyb      .tl_set:N  = \l_keyb_tl,
  keyb      .default:n = { bar },
}
```

the invocation `\keys_set:nn { module } { keya }` will set `\l_keya_tl` to foo, as this is
the default value. But I would like `\keys_set:nn { module } { }` to also *change* the value of the `\l_keya_tl` variable, e.g. to `\c_novalue_tl` so that after setting the keys, I can differentiate between

- the user has not given the key at all (no value supplied)
- the user set the key (with or without an `=`, this is handled by the `.default:n`)

Currently, I just run `\tl_set_eq:NN \l_key_tl \c_novalue_tl` before setting the keys,
then I can test if the user gave the key with

```
\tl_if_novalue:VTF \l_my_tl { no value specified } { handle user value }
```

and of course this works just fine.

**Is it a design choice to *not* provide such features in `l3keys` (e.g. because they are considered poor style), or is this just not implemented as it is not needed often?**

Also note that this beahviour is very similar to using `.initial:n` and then use grouping to set keys locally whenever setting them, so that the `initial:n` never changes. This is, however, not an option for me in some situations.

Currently my approach is to just manually execute an additional `\keys_set:nn { module } { keys, to, preset }`, and then setting the user keys, but this seems tedious.

---

From what gusbrs pointed out, I get that with [How to distinguish "no value" from "empty value" when setting `l3keys`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614690/how-to-distinguish-no-value-from-empty-value-when-setting-l3keys)
can distinguish the situations

- `\keys_set:nn { module } { keya, keyb = bar }`, where the key has been set and no value is provided at all. This will be handled by `.default:n`, which is - if present, equivalent to having called `keya = <default>`
- `\keys_set:nn { module } { keya=, keyb = bar }`, where the key has been explicitly set, but to the empty token list.
- `keys_set:nn { module } { keya = foo, keyb = bar}`, where we regularly set a value

What I want is to also detect the

- `\keys_set:nn { module } { keyb = bar }`  situation, in which case I would e.g. also want to execute the `.default:n` handler (for types that don't support the absence of a value), but in the case of a token list also be able to execute `\tl_set_eq:NN \l_keya_tl \c_novalue_tl` in this case.

I could imagine this to be handled by some kind of `.preset:n` property that gets executed *every time keys are set for this module` before processing the keys, no matter what keys are given.

This would

- guarantee that there is actually a value after setting the keys
- also handle the token list case by specifying `.preset:V = \c_novalue_tl`, which would yield my desired behaviour.

Have a look at the section on 'Presetting keys' in the `xkeyval` documentation, this is what I intend to have.

Comment: The entire `l3keys` concept is that there is no such thing as a key having no value: they exist once you create them and may have an empty value.

Comment: To be clear why I see it that way: keys which are not token lists can't contain no value at all - if you for example have one as an `int`, you need to be able to use the value whether it's set or not.

Comment: But isn't it a reasonably use case to have some key-value syntax macro, say `\foo[key1 = val1, key2 = val2]{something}`, and if `key2`has not been given, we use some kind of fallback, so the key behaves like an optional argument?

Comment: Yes, but even in the case of an int, we might want to *reset* the int to say `0` in case the key is not specified. This way we make sure that the int has a value, but we don't just end up using the int value from the previous invocation, which could be anything.

Comment: The good advice you received notwithstanding: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614690/105447

Comment: @gusbrs Isn't this about differentiating between the key *given* with 'no value' and 'empty value', which is not what I want? I want to differentiate between the `key` not present at all in the key list.

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler It is. I think the parallel I saw is that I use the "no value key" as a UI signal to "unset" some options. But I understand now what you meant, and indeed it is a different need.

Comment: Thinking here: why is `.initial:n` not enough for you?

Comment: @gusbrs initial only initialises the key *once*, namely at the point of expansion of `\keys_define:nn`. I want to have an initial value *every time* keys are set, since this will be a user macro that can be executed several times

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler So what you want to do with this "not present key" depends on local/scoped information which you cannot know in general, if I understand correctly. In this case, I'll leave it to the experts, as I don't know how this can be done...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133675/discussion-between-maximilian-kessler-and-gusbrs).